# Js/Lodash get parent object of array value

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given the following array:

```
var arr = [   { id: '123', numbers: [123,456,789] },  { id: '456', numbers: [6543,344,34534] }]
```

How can I get the parent object of the object containing `123` in the numbers array.

Eg. I want to search `'123'` and get:

```
 { id: '123', numbers: [123,456,789] }
```

I've tried using:

https://lodash.com/docs#find

```
 _.find(arr, 123);
_.findKey(arr,123);
```

Can this be done with _map?
https://lodash.com/docs#map

Comment: In vanilla: `arr.find(x => x.id === '123')`

Comment: Sorry, I assume that should be `arr.find(x => x.numbers.includes(123))`?

Comment: Ugh, your example is misleading, it suggest that you want to find item with `id === '123'`, I'd change it to *I want to search '12' and get:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using `lodash`, you can use `collection.find`.

#### Syntax:

```
_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])
```

`[predicate=_.identity]` is a function that is executed for every iteration. So instead of passing `123`, pass this function.

Note: This can be done using Array functions, but they have compatibility issues and since you are already using lodash, in my understanding, this approach would suit better.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: '123',
  numbers: [123, 456, 789]
}, {
  id: '456',
  numbers: [6543, 344, 34534]
}]

// ES6 version
var r = _.find(arr, x => x.id == '123');

// ES5 version
var r1 = _.find(arr, function(el){ return el.id == '123' });
console.log(r, r1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@gcampbell is correct.

Translate to JavaScript, it should be

```
_.find(arr, function(x) {
    return x.numbers.includes(123);
});
```

You can refer to the [Underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#find) for further information.

Comment: @Rajesh My bad. I intended to use `_.find` and that's a typo.

Comment: Since you're using ES5, you should probably use `indexOf` instead of `includes`.